# Get-ChildItem returns same folder twice

Tags: powershell, get, return, directory

Can somebody tell me why get-childitem returns the same folder twice?

Code

```
$StartTime = (get-date)

new-item "D:\Shares\Vorsorge\000_Musterkunde\Folder" -type directory

Get-ChildItem "D:\Shares\Vorsorge\000_Musterkunde" -Recurse | where-object {$_.CreationTime -gt $starttime}
```

Output

```
Verzeichnis: D:\Shares\Vorsorge\000_Musterkunde


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                                                                              
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                                              
d----        29.01.2014     16:45            Folder                                                                                                                                                                                            
d----        29.01.2014     16:45            Folder
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get-Childitem is only returning 1. The other one is being output by New-Item.  Try this and see if you don't only get one:

```
$StartTime = (get-date)

new-item "D:\Shares\Vorsorge\000_Musterkunde\Folder" -type directory > $null

Get-ChildItem "D:\Shares\Vorsorge\000_Musterkunde" -Recurse | where-object {$_.CreationTime -gt $starttime}
```

Comment: i feel so dumb right now... thanks for the answer though. it works now.